# The value of the integral of function f(x)

Tags: calculus

Let

$$ \mathrm f(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sec^2 x & : & 0 \le x < \frac{1}{4}\pi \\
\sin 2x & : & \frac{1}{4}\pi < x \le \frac{1}{2}\pi
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

How do I find the value of the integral 
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} \mathrm f(x)~\mathrm dx $$

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = \int_a^c f(x)\ dx + \int_c^b f(x)\ dx$

Comment: I don't know how to begin on how to solve these problem

Comment: Note the discontinuity at $x= \pi/4$ and find areas under the separate  curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll follow the hint that Doug M gave, namely that $$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^cf(x)dx + \int_c^bf(x)dx $$

So, $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}f(x)dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx$$

But over these intervals, we know exactly what $f(x)$ looks like! So those integrals just become $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}sec^2(x)dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}sin(2x)dx = 1 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$$

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks guys this helped alot